# Other words for Open Stage "performers"

Tags: word-request

I'm co-hosting open mic/stage events in my town in a non-English speaking country. Shortly, it means that in a certain bar there are both the stage and musical instruments provided by us for anybody to use. It is in our interests to reach international guests to perform onstage, too, via Facebook invitations and status updates and such, in English, that is. I'm wondering what other words there'd be at my disposal in regard to referring to individuals and groups of people apt to perform on an open mic/stage night. So far I've been sticking to "performers". However, I feel that it's sort of too formal. Any suggestions? Should anybody have any experience in such events, I'd be grateful to receive propositions.

Comment: How about _entertainers_ or _troupers_?

Comment: **People** works. Also 'amateur talent' or 'local talent'.  Also, you could mention specific types of performers, such as singers, bands, musicians, comedians, comics, poetry readers, magicians, pets who do tricks, people who do imitations,....

Answer (score 1):

I think that performers is probably the best choice of word. Everything else I can think of would restrict the type of people you're looking for.

For example, you could say *musicians*, but then *singers* might feel excluded, and vice-versa.

You could say *bands*, but that might suggest you don't want solo performers.

Or you could say *artists*, but when used to describe musical acts, that tends to mean it's an established band or performer that people would know.

An *entertainer* (in British English at least) would normally be some sort of all-rounder: a single person who tells jokes, sings songs, dances, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Alan. I was a little vague in my original post, sorry, but all-rounders it is that we're looking for, in a sense that we welcome poets, jugglers and pantomime-artists, bands, singer-songwriters and stand-up comedians equally. You name it, basically. I'm happy that I've got at least one alternative word to use for now. Thanks again.

Comment: In that case, "artists" would be the word I would use.

Comment: You can say stage artists or stage actors.

Answer (score 1):

How about "open talent"? 
Talent is used commonly in the industry to describe a person. E.g: "he is one of the great talents in the comedy world". 
 That way, you can describe the show and the performers equally.

Comment: The word request was for those performing in the show, not the show itself.

Comment: Very well, "open talent" then.

Comment: It wasn't *my* request.  As your answer now stands, it doesn't answer the question.  If "open talent" is your answer, I would suggest the [edit] link.  You could also add a dictionary definition to make your answer especially good.

Comment: ...why does it not answer the question?

Comment: Because the question was about the people in the show, not the show itself.  See my [original comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86402/other-words-for-open-stage-performers/86410?noredirect=1#comment167067_86410)

Comment: As I said: "open talent". <br/>  Talent is used commonly in the industry to describe a person. E.g: "he is one of the great talents in the comedy world". That way, you can describe the show and the performers equally.

Comment: That was in a comment, not the answer.  Your answer is for answering the question.  What goes on in the comments does not make your answer good.

Comment: Well, I like to do things in order, and now that we have agreed, I can correct my answer. Thank you. Goodnight.

Comment: Thank you acekipro and zondo for your input. _Talent_ is also an interesting word of choice, although, you know, I'm quite positive its usage would put a little too much pressure on the people we'd like to set free of their restraints. Sorry for being a little picky here... It's just that I'd like to find something less "augmenting" because we'd like to keep it as low as possible the threshold for anybody to come and entertain others. @zondo